# How to best enhance my program to take advantage of strcmp's timing optimization?

Tags: c, string, optimization, strcmp

I'm currently working on a project that relies on the timing optimization of strcmp. For example, given two strings a1, a2 where a1=a2 and two strings b1, b2 where b1=/=b2  we know that strcmp (a1,a2) will take longer to complete than strcmp(b1,b2) in theory since strcmp finishes once it realizes that one byte in the first string is unequal to the corresponding byte in the second which implies that strcmp will take the longest to complete when the two strings are equal since it needs to iterate over the entire length. My project is currently timing the performance of strcmp using various strings and its success is dependent on one call of strcmp being quicker than another call even if one byte in the two strings being compared is off.

I've created a simpler dummy program to isolate and test the performance (dummy program is below) which compares the performance of comparing two equal strings versus the performance of two unequal strings. Referencing the code, when str3="aaaaaaaaaa" (or any random text that varies greatly from str1) it is very obvious that the first segment comparing two equal strings (str1 and str2) is much slower than the second segment which compares two unequal strings (str2 and str3). However, when switching str3="hellohella" as shown below, the results are very similar and the determination of which segment completes quicker/slower than the other becomes unpredictable. I've also tried using clock() to time the function calls, but that is even more inaccurate than rusage.

Is there any way that I can change my code such that the comparison of the two unequal strings will ALWAYS be decisively faster than the comparison of two equal strings (even if only off by 1 byte)? Are there any C timers that are more accurate than the ones I have tried? Thank you for your time.

```
int main ()
{
    int iterations=10000;
    struct rusage usage;
    struct timeval start, end;

    char * str1="hellohello";
    char * str2="hellohello";
    char * str3="hellohella";
    double tempTotal=0;
    for (int i=0; i<iterations; i++){
            struct rusage usage;
            struct timeval start, end;


            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);
            start=usage.ru_stime;

            for (int j=0; j<100000; j++) strcmp(str1, str2);

            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);
            end=usage.ru_stime;
            double startTime=((double)start.tv_sec + (double)start.tv_usec)/10000;
            double endTime=((double)end.tv_sec+(double)end.tv_usec)/10000;
            tempTotal+=(endTime-startTime);
    }
    printf("Avg time taken: %f\n", tempTotal/iterations);

    printf("\n\n");
    double tempTotal2=0;
    for (int i=0; i<iterations; i++){

            struct rusage usage2;
            struct timeval start2, end2;

            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage2);
            start2=usage2.ru_stime;

            for (int j=0; j<100000; j++) strcmp(str1, str3);

            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage2);
            end2=usage2.ru_stime;

            double startTime2=((double)start2.tv_sec+(double)start2.tv_usec)/10000;
            double endTime2=((double)end2.tv_sec+(double)end2.tv_usec)/10000;
            tempTotal2+=endTime2-startTime2;
    }

    printf("Avg time taken: %f\n", tempTotal2/iterations);
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: But it's not true that unequal strings always take shorter to compare equal strings -- unless you're only interested in strings of the same length.

Comment: Do note that `(double)end2.tv_usec)/10000` should be `(double)end2.tv_usec)/1000000` (in at least 4 different places).

Comment: If your timers aren't accurate enough, you can always increase the number of iterations, of course.  I typically shoot for having the experiment take at least 30 seconds (if not more), and this typically requires tens or hundreds of millions of iterations, or more.  (It's not uncommon to have to use two nested loops, if the number of iterations exceeds that which will fit in a 32-bit int.)  Computers are *fast*.

Comment: @Steve SummitYes sorry I meant to specify that I'm only studying strings of the same length. I will try to implement your other advice, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to consider with your scenario:

- A reasonable compiler will recognize that your strcmp result is
  not used and can safely eliminate the call altogether
- A reasonable
  compiler will recognize that the comparison is loop invariant
  (meaning it doesn't change with the iterations of the loop) and will
  'hoist' the call outside the loop and do it once, then eliminate the
  loop altogether because it doesn't do anything

The easiest way to tackle this is to wrap the strcmp into an external function and put the definition of the function in a different file so the compiler can't do any funny stuff (assuming you don't do cross-file optimization). I would do something like:

```
for (int j=0; j<100000; j++) {
  external_strcmp(str1, str3);
}
```

then put in a different file:

```
int external_strcmp(const char* str1, const char* str2) {
  return strcmp(str1, str2);
}
```

The next thing I would do is make the strings WAAAAYYYYY longer AND increase the number of iterations you do. As it stands, you are likely seeing the overhead of the getrusage() dwarfing the strcmp time.

Good luck. Performance analysis is a very cool area.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately it didn't work. I'm creating a side channel timing attack for fun. In other words my project is taking a hex string of length 40 and brute forcing the bytes one at a time. For the first byte, it checks the timing of strcmp on a test string of equal length. A loop iterates through all hex chars on the first byte of that test string to check which char makes strcmp run slowest; that char is chosen as the correct byte for that position. Repeat for the remaining bytes until both strings are equal. Any other recommendations to to make the timing more accurate?

Comment: I would recommend looking at the generated code from the compiler. If you have included strings.h, it should inline the code for strcmp and you can see what instructions are being generated. One thing you might find is that interesting things might happen to your timings when your string is very short (e.g. 16 bytes or less) or very long (e.g. more than 256 bytes), so you may want to play with the string length more than the contents of the string.